# Conflicting Strings programming competition

Tags: string, algorithm

Given a set of strings, say

```
ap***
ab*le
a****
ab***
```

the problem is to find, given the number of strings and number of allowable differences, whether or not a set of strings is consistent.

So with the above set, the answer is "Yes", if we allow a single inconsistent string (the second one), but "No" if we allow no inconsistent strings.

**What is the best algorithm, and what is the complexity?**

Every single solution I come up with either requires looking at every single combination, or is simply wrong. For example, you can't just go through and add strings to a set (defining distinct as "incompatible"), because then **, ab ad will pass.

The actual problem (from ):
Problem M

In 2417 archaeologists discovered a large collection of 20th century text documents of vital his-
torical importance. Although there were many duplicated documents it was soon evident that, as
well as the damage due to time making much of the text illegible, there were also some disagree-
ments between them. However, it was noticed that groups of texts could be made consistent, i.e.
consistency between texts could be achieved by leaving out some (small) number of texts. For example, the texts:

```
ap***
ab*le
app*e
*p\**e
```

(where * denotes an illegible character) can be made consistent by removing just the second text.

Input will consist of a sequence of sets of texts. Each set will begin with a line specifying the
number of texts in the set, and the maximum number of texts which can be removed. This will be
followed by the individual texts, one per line. Each text consists of at least one and no more than
250 characters, either lower case letters or asterisks. All the texts in a set will be the same length
and there will be no more than 10,000 texts in a set. The sequence of sets is terminated by a line
containing two zeros (0 0).

Output for each set consists of a line containing one of the words ‘Yes’ or ‘No’ depending on
whether or not the set can be made consistent by removing at most the specified number of texts.

```
Sample input
4 1
ap***
ab*le
app*e
*pple
3 1
a
b
c
4 2
fred
ferd
derf
frd*
0 0

Sample output
Yes
No
No
```

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried? (This is probably going to be closed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feels homeworky, so I'm going to leave out a few details.

A [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) can handle this pretty nicely. At any index where a given text contains an `*`, you make that text descend from all other leaves in the trie. Then you walk the trie, looking for any terminal node that matches enough texts.

The trie has at most `n * m` nodes, so adding another text is `O(nm)`.

There's a complication in building the trie too. You have to add texts in the right order, and you have to check the proper order for each text index. Otherwise, you can end up with a situation where `*b` is not contained in the terminal node for `ab`. But doing that doesn't introduce any further algorithmic complexity.

The total time is `O(mn^2)`. Walking the trie once it's built is `O(nm)`, and adding a node is `O(nm)` for `n` nodes.

Answer (score 0):

I propose that you represent a set of consistent strings with a string and a count. The string has a letter at a position where any of the strings in the set has a letter, and an asterisk there otherwise. The count is the number of strings in the set. So {ab**, a*b*} = [abb*, 2].

Start off with a single representation, [****,0].

Each time you see a string X:

1) Add [X,1] to the set of representations

2) If it is consistent with any of the representations so far, create a new representation from the string and the representation - increment the count, and if necessary fix some more letters in the string. Add the new representation to the set of representations.

3) If you now have more than one representation with the same string, keep just one, with the count the maximum of those with that string.

4) Remove representations whose count is less than the number of strings seen so far minus the number of strings you are allowed to leave out.

5) - repeat from (1) with the next string

At the end the most plausible answer, if any, is the one with the largest count. Any consistent answer will have been created. The maximum number of representations on hand at any one time is the maximum number of possible answers at that stage, which is Choose(n, x) where N is the number of strings seen at that point and x is the number of texts you are allowed to discard. If x = 1 this is n(n-1)/2. You have to do this n times, and the other costs grow only with the length of the string, so I guess you have an O(mn^3) algorithm.